# Implement a multimodel control system

Tags: microcontroller, control-system, pid-controller

I am asking you how would i be able to implement a multimodel system using RC filters.I need a nonlinear model and my teacher told me to use RC filters.By using  a RC filter i get a first order system and i would need a switch that would add to the circuit another RC filter which would make the system a second order.
I would then use my development board and implement 2 PID controls that would commute depending on the situation.

I am not sure about the electrical design still.
Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing you need to know when designing any system is what it's supposed to do. Nobody can give you any help without that apart from suggesting you enter "multimodal systems" into Google and get reading.

Comment: Well this is the problem...i need a nonlinear process that i can implement and control.The main task is implementing the algorhytm for controlling it..but i still have to figure out how will i create the target process that will be controlled.And as i said my teacher suggested using a first order filter then adding another one to make a second order system.